# Oracle database throwing error - orapw[SID] is missing

Tags: oracle, passwords

I have downloaded and installed Oracle Database Express edition. In SQL Developer, I am trying to create a new database connection that connects to SYS, however I am being rejected with the error:
 Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

I found out that during installation I should have been prompted to create a password for sys, but no such thing happened. 
 I then tried to find the orapw[SID] file in /database. It was not there.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you open a command prompt window and execute `sqlplus / as sysdba`? If you manage to connect to the database, modify SYS password using `alter user sys identified by its_new_password;`

Comment: The error message is saying the TNS listener doesn't recognise the specified SID. It doesn't seem to be related to any password issue. What did you specify in the connection, how is that defined in tnsnames.ora, and what services are known to the listener? `tnsping yoursid` may give you some clues.